# MCMC Prior: concave quadratic functions

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, prior, gaussian-process, polynomial, pymc

I am currently running into a problem with MCMC. I am using it to evaluate different amounts of clusters (n_clusters, in [2,300]) of a graph that is varying in time. I want to achieve a clustering where the aggregate data in time follows most closely a concave (a<0) quadratic function (a*t**2+b*t+c).

So far, I am estimating in my chain simply [a,b,c and n_clusters], and evaluating the mean RMSE over all clusters as a potential (in pymc). This is of course less than optimal because it creates only a single polynomial, to which all clusters are compared. The chain is not converging very well and I believe this is simply not an ideal solution.

Now, I'd like to use something more expressive. Is there a way for me to use e.g. a Gaussian Process with a mean convex quadratic function, while making sure that its second derivative is always negative (i.e. a<0)? This could be the common prior for all clusters and their data. And do I get a quick likelihood measure of the GP fit to each clusters' data?

Edit: Note that I'm not simply estimating [a,b,c] for each clusters because the number of clusters changes between samples. I wonder if the chain can still converge if I do this and am running tests right now.

Thanks in advance,
Thierry